# Envelope theorem for discrete choice sets?

Tags: mathematical-economics, choice-theory

If we have a function
$$f(x)=\max_yg(x,y)$$

Then we can find the derivative $d/dx \ f(x)$ by realizing that 
$$(1): \quad \frac {\partial }{\partial y}g(x,y^*)=0$$
because of the first order condition for maximization.

We can use this by recognizing that $$\frac d {dx}f(x)=\frac d {dx}g(x,y^*(x))=\frac \partial {\partial x}g(x,y^*)+\frac \partial {\partial y}g(x,y^*)\frac {dy^*(x)} {dx}=\frac \partial {\partial x}g(x,y^*)$$
Where the last equality follows because of result $(1)$.

---

However, my question is, **what if $y$ can only take a discrete number of values**? such as $0$ or $1$? We can of course say:

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
g_x(x,0) \quad \text { if } g(x,0) > g(x,1)\\
g_x(x,1) \quad \text { if } g(x,0) < g(x,1)
\end{cases}$$

**However, I am wondering if there is a kind of "envelope theorem for discrete choice sets", that would allow us to simplify this (especially if the choice set is discrete but large).**

Comment: @denesp the OP wants to take the derivative with respect to the parameter $x$, and not the (discrete) choice variable $y$. Presumably a classical definition of the derivative with respect to $x$ can be applied here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an envelope theorem for the setting you describe.

Have a look at “[Envelope Theorems for Arbitrary Choice Sets](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1468-0262.00296/abstract)” by Milgrom and Segal (2002).

Comment: I have tried to apply it in a very simple case. Perhaps I am confused as to the meaning of the theorem, but here is a question I asked about it: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/20001/does-the-envelope-theorem-hold-at-a-corner-solution